# Issue displaying image

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-preprocessing

I am stuck on data preprocessing for a CNN that I'm trying to design. Here is the code:

```
import os, shutil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import seaborn as sns
import random
import re
from PIL import Image

main_path = '/Users/myusername/Downloads/Rice_Image_Dataset'

labels = []
train_images = []

for file in os.listdir(main_path):
    if file == '.DS_Store' or file == 'Rice_Citation_Request.txt':
        continue
    labels.append(file)
    for label in labels:
        folder = os.path.join(main_path, label)
        for img in os.listdir(folder):
            train_images.append(img)
        

labels

len(labels)    

len(train_images)

file_counts = {}

for img_path in train_images:
    img_file_name = os.path.basename(img_path)
    
    for label in labels:
        if img_file_name.lower().startswith(label.lower()):
            if label not in file_counts:
                file_counts[label] = 0
            file_counts[label] += 1
            break

# Create a pandas DataFrame for the table
file_counts_df = pd.DataFrame(list(file_counts.items()), columns=["Label", "File Count"])
print(file_counts_df)

sample_images = []

for label in labels:
    image_path = os.path.join(main_path, label)
    for img in os.listdir(image_path):
        if img.lower().startswith(label.lower()) and re.search(r'\(1\)', img):
           sample_images.append(img)
print(sample_images)

for file in sample_images:
    # Get the label from the file path
    label = os.path.dirname(file)
    label = os.path.basename(label)

    if label in labels:
        # Read and display the image
        img = np.asarray(Image.open(file))
        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.title(os.path.basename(file))
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()
    else:
        continue
```

My issue is that last step, where I'm trying to display the images, is simply not returning anything. I created a list of files called sample_images to store the first file in each of the five folders, and I would like to display each image in this list.
Here is where I got my data: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/muratkokludataset/rice-image-dataset

Comment: so you are saying that `plt.show()` is not working, but are you sure that it's been reached? like adding a print inside that if statement

Comment: as in print(plt.show()) @AlbertoSinigaglia?

Comment: no, as for `if ...: print("test") ...`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Yeah nothing shows up.

Comment: Then you see, the problem is somewhere else, that `if label in labels` is always false